# How to make two Stellar nodes run for History Archive?

Tags: stellar-core, history

I tried to run two Stellar nodes to make History Archive happen.

But this is the log I received:

```
2020-01-30T12:09:21.894 <startup> [default INFO] RUN_STANDALONE enabled in configuration file - node will not function properly with most networks

2020-01-30T12:09:21.899 GBU3I [default INFO] Starting stellar-core 65c3b44c

2020-01-30T12:09:21.899 GBU3I [Database INFO] Connecting to: postgresql://dbname=zagaz_core_01 host=localhost user=zagaz 
password=********

2020-01-30T12:09:22.015 GBU3I [SCP INFO] LocalNode::LocalNode@GBU3I qSet: 268bbe

2020-01-30T12:09:22.063 GBU3I [default INFO] Listening on 127.0.0.1:11525 for HTTP requests

2020-01-30T12:09:22.120 GBU3I [History INFO] Archive 'vs' has 'put' and 'get' commands, will be read and written

2020-01-30T12:09:22.120 GBU3I [Ledger INFO] Starting up application

2020-01-30T12:09:22.120 GBU3I [default INFO] Connection effective settings:

2020-01-30T12:09:22.121 GBU3I [default INFO] TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS: 8

2020-01-30T12:09:22.121 GBU3I [default INFO] 
MAX_ADDITIONAL_PEER_CONNECTIONS: 64

2020-01-30T12:09:22.121 GBU3I [default INFO] MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS: 500

2020-01-30T12:09:22.121 GBU3I [default INFO] MAX_OUTBOUND_PENDING_CONNECTIONS: 16

2020-01-30T12:09:22.121 GBU3I [default INFO] MAX_INBOUND_PENDING_CONNECTIONS: 484

2020-01-30T12:09:22.121 GBU3I [default INFO] Loading last known ledger

2020-01-30T12:09:22.128 GBU3I [Ledger INFO] Loaded last known ledger: [seq=2022, hash=ab63e7]

2020-01-30T12:09:22.130 GBU3I [Overlay INFO] Binding to endpoint 0.0.0.0:11526

2020-01-30T12:09:22.135 GBU3I [default INFO] ll?level=trace -> {
   "Global" : "Trace"
}

2020-01-30T12:48:37.045 GBU3I [Overlay TRACE] OverlayManagerImpl tick [OverlayManagerImpl.cpp:399]

2020-01-30T12:48:37.045 GBU3I [default DEBUG] Estimated clock loop idle: 99% (512/513)
```